# Как можно распечатать ответ?

Tags: поддержка

Я хочу распечатать [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454264/227016) на вопрос [Книги и учебные ресурсы по С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454263/227016)

Если я просто нажму <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, то распечатается также и текст вопроса, который мне не очень нужен.

Как я могу распечатать только ответ?

Comment: Скопируйте ответ в какой-нибудь внешний редактор, например, в Microsoft Word или OpenOffice, и распечатайте оттуда.

Comment: @Arhad, спасибо так и сделал. Вероятно, это не сработает в общем случае (например, когда в ответе есть код), но для этого ответа подошло)

Comment: можно попробовать зайти в ревизию и оттуда печатать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/454264/22

Comment: Для печати нашел [StackPrinter](https://stackapps.com/q/179), но он всё равно оперирует вопросами, а не отдельными сообщениями.

Comment: Кратко: `curl | pandoc | lpr`. Подробнее завтра.

Comment: @NickVolynkin я уже распечатал методом копирования в word, так что можно хоть послезавтра) А вообще предложение печатать из ревизии очень хорошее, если ещё в инструментах разработчика удалить блок с номером ревизии. Про `curl | pandoc | lpr` тоже было бы интересно узнать.

Comment: Волшебный инструмент ножницы помогут вам...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Конфигурация**
>
> Google Chrome 70.0.3538.77
>
> Opera 56.0.3051.99
>
> Яндекс.Браузер 18.9.1.954

**1 этап** — выделяем весь необходимый текст.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**2 этап** — вызываем контекстное меню и выбираем "Печать".

[image: Контекстное меню]

**3 этап** — Завершаем процесс настройкой и дальнейшей отправкой документа на печать.

[image: Печать]